# How to compile a compiled template in angularjs

Tags: templates, angularjs, compilation, directive

I want to be able to have the second directive *phone* compiled to alert, how should I do this

```
<div ng-app="website">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">    
        <div phonebook="phone">  PhoneBook</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x3azn/GzsQJ/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the compile in the `phone` directive and I believe the restrict is case sensitive:

http://jsfiddle.net/GzsQJ/4/

```
.directive('phone', function(){
    return {
        //HERE IS THE PROBLEM, THIS DIRECTIVE DOES NOT COMPILE
        restrict: 'AC',
        link: function(s,e,a){
             e.bind('click', function(){
                alert('clicked');
            })

        }
    }
});
```

In addition, I added the directive to the phonebook's template:

```
var template = '<div ng-class="{phone: number}" phone>Phone</div>';
// or '<div class="phone">Phone</div>'
```

I'm not sure it will work in a `ngclass` directive but the above demo does work.